# Access value of an HTML5 canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am new to HTML5.

With a typical element and something like jQuery I am typically able to access its value with

```
$("#elem").val();
```

EDIT:
say i write `"abcd"` in the canvas element ..i want to be able to "store" "abcd" in a database somewhere...

if it were pure text i would access it as shown above with jquery but with a drawing im not sure how it would work?

how do i achieve the same result with a canvas element? and what format can i expect the result in? Would I have to get an array of all x,y coordinates and parse that some how? do i get an image?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? To select the canvas element or the content of the canvas?

Comment: say i write "abcd" in the canvas element ..i want to be able to "store" "abcd" in a database somewhere...if it were pure text i would access it as shown above with jquery but with a drawing im not sure how it would work?

Comment: edited the question to make it clear

Comment: it's almost impossible, except if you want to save the image instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `getImageData()` method. This returns an `ImageData` object. `ImageData` contains a `width` property, a `height` property and a `CanvasPixelArray` object which is essentially a bitmap. ImageData is probably most useful for loading data back into a canvas (using the `putImageData()` method), but you can also examine the raw data of the pixel array if you so desire.

[You can read more about ImageData here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/ImageData)

[And you can read about canvas pixel manipulation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)

---

It appears that I may have misunderstood your question. If by storing "abcd" in your database, you wish to store the bitmapped image, then you simply need to extract the pixel data and then store it as a BLOB or similar object. This is what I assumed you meant.

If however you wish to store the actual text "abcd" in your database, you are going to have a much more difficult time. You need to think of canvas as a literal canvas. Once you put something on it, it becomes part of the image. It isn't like SVG where specific components can be extracted back out again. Canvas is essentially a bitmap image, so if you wish to extract textual data from it without having access to the design algorithm you would have to use some sort of OCR algorithm (which would of course be highly unadvisable).

If you do indeed wish to extract textual data, I recommend that you take a look at SVG which is more flexible in some respects. [MDN has a series of fairly comprehensive articles on the subject.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/SVG)

Comment: this will save the canvas as an image, but not the text inside the canvas. @algorithmicCoder asked to be able to "store" "abcd" in a database.

Comment: Was he referring to the text or the bitmap? Maybe OP can clarify.

Comment: the text/how to get the actual text is ideal but the bitmap or some intermediate format that helps with the ultimate goal of getting to the text is ok as well.

Comment: You can get the bitmap as I mentioned in my answer (using ImageData) and then analyse it, but I really don't recommend doing it. You'll be hard pressed to get an algorithm fast enough and accurate enough. You should **really** try to find another way to achieve your desired result that doesn't involve analysing canvas data.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas doesn't store objects everything is just rasterized image. So if you want to access to canvas data as objects you have to use canvas libs i.e [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)